# How to scrape Data `Lamp In Box` in this string using `RegExp` in following string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to **scrape** Data `Lamp In Box` in this string using `RegExp` in following string -

I want to **scraped** `1 Units` using regexp

I have write below regexp but its not working.

Regexp - `Lamp In Box: '(.*)(s)<\/td>`

```
`<td><b>Price:</b></td>         <td>
                                                                                        <br />Free Ground Shipping&nbsp;<span class="show_free_shipping" style="color:red;">[?]</span>
                                <br />Ship From United States
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                                                <tr>
                            <td><b>Availability:</b></td>
                            <td>
                                                        <b style="color:blue;">In Stock</b>
                                                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><b>Lamp In Box:</b></td>
                            <td>1 Unit(s)</td>
                        </tr>
    
                                            </table>
`
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this? There are parsers that will make this easier and more reliable. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php If you were to use a regex why would you want `([A-Z a-z])\w+`, that is checking for a capital letter, lower case letter, or space, and then one or more letters, numbers or underscores.

Comment: I want to extract `Lamp In Box:</b></td><td>1 Unit(s)</td>` this data only. How Can I write Regexp for this .

Comment: @chris85 I am scrapping data from this url using file_get_contents method view-source:http://www.apexlamps.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=29

Comment: Your updated regex is not strict and is **highly** likely to get incorrect data/fail unexpectedly. The `()` have special meaning in regex and should be escaped when expected to be literal. You will be better off using a parser, look at the link I posted.

Comment: @chris85 Can you please write a regexp in my condition .. I am newbie for this

Comment: What is your end goal? What do you want to select? In your question you mentioned you want `1 Units` but in the comments you said you want `Lamp In Box:</b></td><td>1 Unit(s)</td>`. What chris is telling you is that regex is most likely the best tool for your job, so you might want to look at the link he provided instead :)

Answer (score 2):

For catching the number of Lamp In Box you can try the next:

```
$string = <<your input string>>;
$pattern = '/Lamp In Box:.*\s*.*?(\d+) Unit\(s\)/i';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $result);
```

The `$result` would contain what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next regular expression, if I correctly understand you:
 `/(<td>).*Lamp In Box:.*\s*.*?(<\/td>)/i`

 
 So, you can test this by:

```
$string = <<your input string>>;
$pattern = '/(<td>).*Lamp In Box:.*\s*.*?(<\/td>)/i';
$replacement = '$1$2';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

This replaces all that are inside of `<td></td>` which contains `Lamp In Box`

Comment: The OP is looking to capture the number of units, not replace the cells contents (or I misread).

Comment: Thank you for correcting my misreading =) I answered for this case too.